# Show more digits in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, digits

Let's say I have:

```
echo 1/3;
```

And it print out only 0.33333333333333, can I get more digits?

Comment: Add another `echo 1/3;`, then you have two numbers. Or did you mean *digits*? ;)

Comment: what are you doing that this amount of precision isnt enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can use [`bcdiv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
echo bcdiv(1, 3, 20);
```

The third argument

> is used to set the number of digits after the decimal place in the result. You can also set the global default scale for all functions by using bcscale().

Comment: There's no floating point when I use bcdiv?
Like in Stefan's answer?

Comment: @Templar the [numbers are represented as strings](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php), so you can have precision until you run out of memory :)

Answer (score 3):

Edit the [`precision`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) configuration variable either in your `php.ini` or some other configuration location or use [`ini_set()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

```
ini_set('precision', 22);
echo 1/3;
// 0.3333333333333333148296
```

Even though I highly doubt that you really need that kind of precision ;-)

**EDIT**

As Gordon said: you'll hit the floating point precision limit in PHP sooner or later (depending on the precision specified). So the better way would be to use either the [**BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension or the [**GNU Multiple Precision**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension, if you're after real high precision mathematics.

Comment: this will give odd results though: 0.333333333333333314829616256247390

Comment: Sure... That's floating point precision limitation. So generally using `gmp` or `BC math` would be the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

You might want tto look into the BC arbitary precision php library
http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 1):

The setting is `precision`: http://es.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

However, I would not use it except for debugging purposes. Have a look at [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)