# scientific notation showing up in php

Tags: php, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show more digits in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492028/show-more-digits-in-php)

Let me give some background information about my problem. We have an old legacy application which is being migrated to a different server. In the new server we find that long floating point numbers are getting printed in scientific notations - this was not the case in our previous server.

E.g.:

```
$num1 = 60000000000.0;
$num2 = 2000000000.0;
$sum  = $num1 + $num2;
echo $sum; //prints 6.2E+10 in new server but 62000000000 in old one..
```

Now, I do know that we can use `number_format()` or `printf()` etc to fix this. However my problem is that such calculations are far too many in the application and it will be very difficult to change all instances.

So can anyone help me with my situation? Is there a global solution? Something configurable maybe in php.ini or something? Can anyone give me any pointers why this works fine in old server but not in new? What server settings might be causing this?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you still have access to the old server, do a `phpinfo()` on both servers and compare them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the `precision` ini setting:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision

Will differ result, is capped on top. Your data as an example on some random system and the precision setting (it defaulted to 14 on that system):

```
 0: 6.0E+10     7: 6.2E+10        14: 62000000000
 1: 6.0E+10     8: 6.2E+10        15: 6.2E+10    
 2: 6.2E+10     9: 6.2E+10        16: 6.2E+10    
 3: 6.2E+10    10: 6.2E+10        17: 6.2E+10    
 4: 6.2E+10    11: 62000000000    18: 6.2E+10    
 5: 6.2E+10    12: 62000000000    19: 6.2E+10    
 6: 6.2E+10    13: 62000000000    20: 6.2E+10
```

Comment: and there is really no dupe for that?

Comment: Probably so. The one you linked to is not entirely perfect. Couldn't find another great match...

Comment: Sadly, the precision value is the same in both server's php.ini (12)